# Como obtener un arreglo en la solicitud get que le hacen a una API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

De una pagina me llega una peticion a una accion en mi controlador api controller, las peticiones me la estan haciendo por Get y me estan enviando estos parametros:

```
Array(

[message_type] => CHECKOUT_COMPLETED 
[message_description] => Order # order8d6934b72615a63 has been completed
[merchant_order_id] => order8d6934b72615a63 
[merchant_transaction_id] => [merchant_subscription_id] => [txn_id] => 
BA416BD9D3994074AEDE909506B655A7 [merchant_token_id] => [mac] => 
e4effc8d5fd57ca61034c01a7c51b58b 

)
```

en mi api controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
    // GET: api/OrderResult
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {     
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Por favor alguien pudiera guiarme como obtener ese array que me envian en mi accion Get de la Api.

Comment: por GET no te puede enviar esa informacion, salvo que de alguna forma la este poniendo como parte de la url. Si vas a enviar datos complejos deberia ser por POST y en el body definir un json

Comment: como recibes en el action los datos sino hay ningun parametro que pueda aplicar el model binding ?

Comment: tengo el Get y el Post, al ponerle un punto a cada uno para debuguear, el post nunca se me activa, por eso digo que me lo estan enviando por Get que es el que se me activa al debuguear, no estoy seguro, estoy iniciandome con  esto de la API

Comment: Habria que ver como es tu llamada entonces. porque deberia ser por post

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de como invocas a esa api, mas que nada para nalaizar como envias los datos. Ademas tambien la implementacion del post

Comment: bueno el problema esta que es una respuesta que me da evo snap una solucion para pago a travez de api, que cuando se realiza el pago te devuelve la respuesta a una url que le pasas por parametro, lo que se es que me envia el array que mostre arriba pero no se como me lo envia